# To export data from a table to another table using PL/SQL

Tags: loops, for-loop, plsql, count

I have two tables called "Table_1" and "Table_2".
Table_2 has not data. It has only columns called "City" and "Count of University".
Table_1 is:

```
 City           University
 -------------------------
 Istanbul          ITU
 Istanbul      Bogazici Uni
 Istanbul          YTU
 Istanbul        Koc Uni
 Ankara           METU
 Ankara        Hacettepe Uni
 Ankara         Baskent Uni
 Trabzon           KTU
```

I want to export cities  and count of universities from Table_1 to Table_2 using PL/SQL. So Table_2 is looks like:

```
  City              Count of University
  -------------------------------------
  Istanbul                 4
  Ankara                   3
  Trabzon                  1
```

How can I do that? I know that I need to use loops but I don't know how to use.
I want to learn usable code.

Comment: You do not need plsql for that. Sql will be enough `insert into table_2 (select city,count(*) from table_1 group by city)`

Comment: I know that and I know how to do that. But, both I want to learn PL/SQL and it is my mentor's request. I am intern.

Comment: Asking someone to do it for you isn't learning though...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
insert into table_2 SELECT City, count(1) total FROM table_1 group by City
```

Comment: I know that and I know how to do that. But, both I want to learn PL/SQL and it is my mentor's request. I am intern.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using any PLSQL here. You can achieve this using a simple query. To illustrate this , the below query will generate the data for your table 2:

```
SELECT City, count(1) "Count of University" 
FROM table_1 
group by City;
```

Second part it to populate it, so you can use the below query to populate it.

```
insert into table_2 
SELECT City, 
count(1) total 
FROM table_1 
group by City
```

PLSQL Anonymous block for the above :

```
declare

begin

Insert into table_2 
SELECT City, 
      count(1)  
FROM table_1 
group by City;

commit;    

exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode||'-'||sqlerrm);
end;
```

Comment: I know that and I know how to do that. But, both I want to learn PL/SQL and it is my mentor's request. I am intern

Comment: Check my post . Always makes things simple rather can complete it

Comment: Thanks for your post. It is really simple but I need to use loops. It is better for me . But thanks.

Comment: Dear, you need to learn first how PL/SQL engine works. Stored procedures comes very later. Start from simple things first and then build your base and then gain strength in the subject. You simply cannot jump to top. Also using loop is not a good practice when you can use it in much simpler way. It increases overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, also read on [cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html) , [procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm), [for loops](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155)

```
create or replace procedure copyTable is 
 cursor source_table is 
   select city,count(*) as total from table_1 group by city;
begin 
 for item in source_table loop
   insert into table_2(City,Count_of_University) values (item.city,item.total);
 end loop;
end;
```

Comment: @Raj_Te As he has mentioned - he is intern, trying to learn pl/sql. So I think that better to start with simple things first. Also he *'needs to use loops'*. However, feel free to offer alternative solution with Bulk collect.

Comment: Well so you think for a intern using cursor is a better way to start...!!! I dont think his mentor would had expected the above..

Comment: @Raj_Te And again as i understand it - his mentor's requirement is to **use loops** ... anyway let him decide for himself.

Comment: Thanks the procedure Works correctly but I can't see Table_2, I wrote "select * from Table_2" but I can see only columns. I wrote "commit;" but it is not correct. How can I see Table_2?

Comment: @yilmazosmanfurkan61 call the procedure like this `begin  copyTable; commit; end;`  This should be executed as script. Then `select * from Table_2`. Also make sure Table_1 is not empty.

Comment: For a person who not even know how to execute a proc, you expect him to learn loop at the start. Strange. Try anonymous blocks first..

Comment: @Raj_Te I know how to execute.

Comment: @yilmazosmanfurkan61 I had an extra select in code, which i just removed. try getting and running the code again.

Comment: the procedure is created. It is okay. But "begin copyTable; commit; end;" is giving error.

Comment: I found: I wrote group by City, University

Comment: @yilmazosmanfurkan61 Depends on the error ;-) What is the error message?

Comment: @Plirkee   When I wrote group by City, University, it works correctly. You forgot to add University in group by . Thanks for your help, it works.

Comment: @yilmazosmanfurkan61 You should't be grouping by University, as you want to count universities in the same city. I think something else was the matter.  Also when you confirm that it works - you should accept the answer.